# Creating jQuery Tooltips on newly created links

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm using this jQuery Tooltip plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

I create tooltips for all links when the document is ready, like that:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').tooltip();
});
```

But when I add some links to the document later, the plugin won't display jQuery tooltip on them.

I expected that when I call `$('a').tooltip();` again after I created those new links, jQuery will create tooltips for them too. It won't, it'll even ruin all jQuery tooltips I have.

How can I create tooltips on newly created links? Is it possible to release the current tooltips and call it again on all links or something like that? Or can I create the tooltips for links that haven't been created yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/08/19/new-plugin-live-query/) to do this:

```
$("a").liveQuery(function(){
  $(this).tooltip();
});
```

As for not adding tooltips to links that have already been processed (I don't think livequery will do that anyway), (but if for some reason it did) you could add a class "tt-processed" to links after they've been modified, and from then on out only select for links that don't have that class.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. btw. It's livequery (with lowercased Q).

Comment: Sorry, I'm too accustomed to saying "jQuery," the big-Q comes natural ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
$(e).append("<a>some link</a>").tooltip();
```